# Android dialog not showing up

Tags: android, dialog

I have a `TextView` and once I click on it a dialog will open which utilizes a date and time picker as its view.

datetimepicker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </DatePicker>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TimePicker>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/setcancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SET" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CANCEL" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this the code for `TextView.OnClickListener`

```
final TextView startTime = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView3);     
       startTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datetimepicker);
            dialog.setTitle("Set Date and Time");

            Button set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
            tp.setCurrentHour(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            tp.setCurrentMinute(Calendar.MINUTE);
            tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;
                }
            });
            set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startTime.setText(Integer.toString(hour)+ ";" + Integer.toString(min));             
                }
            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });



        }
    });
```

The problem is once I click on the `TextView` it does nothing, I mean nothing happens and I wanted to set the text of the `TextView` with the time set by the user once OK button is clicked on the dialog.

Do you have any suggestion? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call

```
Dialog.show()
```

Comment: one last question when i click on the set button how can i set the text on the textview on button click?

Comment: I think you are already doing that with this line: " startTime.setText(Integer.toString(hour)+ ";" + Integer.toString(min));"?